# How to detect Sonos volume changes

Tags: sonos

I can set the volume of a Sonos on my network sending a POST in the proper envelope/xml format.

What I can't figure out is how to detect when the volume changed from another client.

I noticed that when I change the volume thru the phone app the Controller on the computer changes as well and real time. I would like to replicate that behavior.

I have sniffed the network and I didn't see any http calls on that regard, perhaps I have missed something. I am ok in doing whatever I have to implement, I just don't have a clue on how they do it.

I do see some tcp packets streamed but not documentation or leads helped there either. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get an event on the RenderingControl service. You have registered for events I assume?